# prettier-atom stopped working - single quote error

Tags: prettier

prettier-atom was working great with .js files, but after running it on a package.json file (auto-format on save was enabled) it stopped working and gave me the following error:

"prettier-atom failed: Invalid singleQuote value. Expected true or false, but received "true" "

[image: prettier-atom error]

I tried to change my .prettierrc from

```
"singleQuote": true,
```

to

```
"singleQuote": false,
```

but I don't know where to do this.  There are 31 different .prettierrc files on my (Windows) system and I don't know which one to change, nor do I know if the change will fix the error.  I have re-started atom but no luck.

I will add *.json to configuration overrides, but I still don't know how to "clear" the error.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.  I was going to delete the entire thread but this may help someone else.

1. To configure prettier, I blew off .prettierrc and just updated package.json
2. I changed the prettier object member from

   "prettier": {
       "singleQuote": "true"
     },

to

```
  "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true
  },
```

Sorry to waste your time but I assure you that I wasted a lot more time than you may have on this.

Comment: we do have `jsxSingleQuote` here in [prettier defined options](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#jsx-quotes)